# Angular - check if class is odd or even on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following ng-repeat that gives an element a className based on whether it is even or odd...

```
<div ng-click="displayHTML(content)" ng-class-odd="'title'" ng-class-even="'html'" ng-repeat="content in name.name">
    {{content}}
</div>
```

On `ng-click` I am calling `displayHTML()` and passing a parameter `content` so that only that particular div that is clicked calls the function.

However on ng-click I'm attempting to see whether the clicked element is `ng-class-odd` or `ng-class-even` and I want the function to only be called if the element is `ng-class-odd`.

But I do not know an easy way to do this. Is there an easy "angular" way of doing it. If not, what should I put here...

```
$scope.displayHTML = function(obj){
////    

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) exposes several local variables to the scope, specifically `$even` and `$odd`. Just use those:

```
<div ng-click="displayHTML(content, $even)" ng-class-odd="'title'" ng-class-even="'html'" ng-repeat="content in name.name">
    {{content}}
</div>
```

js:

```
$scope.displayHTML = function(obj, $even) {
    if($even) {/* even code*/}
    else {/* odd code */}
}
```